# Nginx - Deny folder, except subfolders with regex

Tags: nginx, regex

I want to deny access to anything in the `app` directory, except in subfolders with an `Assets` folder.

For example:

Allow these files

`/app/bundles/ApiBundle/Assets/css/Thing.js
/app/bundles/AssetsBundle/Assets/css/mautic.css`

Deny these:
```
/app/bundles/Whatever/Config/config.php
/app/bundles/AppCache.php
/app/whatever.php

This works fine (https://serverfault.com/a/450378/310646)... if I don't use regex.

For example, this works:

```
location ^~ /app/bundles/ApiBundle/Assets/ {
    allow all;
}

location ^~ /app/ { 
    deny all; 
}
```

but this does not:

```
location ^~ /app/bundles/.+/Assets/ {
    allow all;
}

location ^~ /app/ { 
    deny all; 
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

```
location ~ /app/bundles/.*/Assets/ {
    allow all;
    access_log off;
}
location ~ /app/ { deny all; }
```

BUT... this needs to be above any other location blocks that may have an effect on it (like `location ~ \.php$` for example).

Using `^~` is before regex and won't work with regex....